# Point on surface closest to a plane using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the point on $z=1-2x^2-y^2$ closest to $2x+3y+z=12$ using Lagrange multipliers.

I recognize $z+2x^2+y^2=1$ as my constraint but am unable to recognize the distance squared I am trying to minimize in terms of 3 variables. May someone help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [squared distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html) between a point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and the plane $2x + 3y + z = 12$ is given by

$$ f(x_0,y_0,z_0) = \frac{(2x_0 + 3y_0 + z_0 - 12)^2}{2^2 + 3^2 + 1^2} = \frac{(2x_0 + 3y_0 + z_0 - 12)^2}{14}. $$

Thus, in order to find the point in your surface that is closest to the plane, it is enough to minimze

$$ g(x,y,z) = (2x + 3y + z - 12)^2 $$

subject to the constraint

$$ 2x^2 + y^2 + z = 1. $$

Answer (score 3):

A simpler approach for computing the distance between these objects: the given plane is orthogonal to the vector $(2,3,1)^T$, so the point(s) on the surface of minimal distance from the plane are the ones for which the tangent plane of the surface at such point(s) is orthogonal su $(2,3,1)^T$. If for some $k$
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 2x^2+y^2+z &=& 1 \\ 2x+3y+z &=& k \end{array}\right. $$
has exactly one solution, such a solution is a point of minimal distance. By eliminating $z$, we are looking for the values of $k$ such that
$$ 2x^2-2x+y^2-3y = 1-k $$
has exactly one solution. By completing the squares, it is trivial that the only point of minimal distance occurs at $(x,y)={\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)}$, from which $(x,y,z)=\color{red}{\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},-\frac{7}{4}\right)}$ and
$$ d(\text{plane},\text{surface}) = \frac{\left|2\cdot\frac{1}{2}+3\cdot\frac{3}{2}-\frac{7}{4}-12\right|}{\sqrt{3^2+2^2+1^2}}=\color{red}{\frac{33}{4\sqrt{14}}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $F(x,y,z) = z+ 2x² + y² = 1$, as a level set of F. So that $\nabla F= (4x,2y,1)$. Now you have to remember the distance between point-plane in $\mathbb{R}³$:

$D(x,y,z) = \frac{ax+by+cz+d}{\sqrt{a²+b²+c²}}$. Applying that for our plane, we have that $D(x,y,z) = \frac{2x+3y+1z-12}{\sqrt{14}}$. Hence,

$\nabla D= (2/\sqrt{14}, 3/\sqrt{14},1/\sqrt{14}).$

Now, utilizing Lagrange's multipliers we must solve this system:

$\nabla D = \lambda \nabla F$

$2x+3y+z=12$

Comment: Actually would D(x,y,z) be the absolute of what you have written . But then we'd need on how to calculate partial derivatives when we have an absolute value sign, so we break up the function into a piecewise one?

Comment: Also, the constraint should be the surface not the plane.